# Multiple Dynamic SiteEdit CPs on a Page

Tags: tridion, siteedit

We have SiteEdit 2009 SP2 in SDL Tridion 2009 SP1 and it is working fine for normal published pages. It is also working ok if we have single Dynamic Component Presentation (DCP) in a page. But when we have multiple DCPs on the page, it is taking the first one only and ignoring all others.

Here is my code

```xml
<xsl:variable name="SE_CP_MarkUP">
<![CDATA[ <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: {"ID" : "cp_%ID%", "ComponentID" : "%ID%", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:XX-XXXXX-32", "Version" : 0, "IsQueryBased" : true  } -->]]>
```

I am using this variable in loop

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="XXXX:RegexStringReplace($SE_CP_MarkUP,'%ID%',@ID)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Please suggest what could be the issue?

More Detail:

Generated  HTML

```
    <div>
  <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: {"ID" : "cp_tcm:13-287142", "ComponentID" : "tcm:13-287142", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:13-286965-32", "Version" : 3, "IsQueryBased" : true  } -->
  HTMLConent
</div>
<div>
  <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: {"ID" : "cp_tcm:13-287162", "ComponentID" : "tcm:13-287162", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:13-286965-32", "Version" : 2, "IsQueryBased" : true  } -->
  HTMLConent
</div>
<div>
  <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: {"ID" : "cp_tcm:13-287204", "ComponentID" : "tcm:13-287204", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:13-286965-32", "Version" : 1, "IsQueryBased" : true  } -->
  HTMLConent
</div>
<div>
  <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: {"ID" : "cp_tcm:13-287234", "ComponentID" : "tcm:13-287234", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:13-286965-32", "Version" : 4, "IsQueryBased" : true  } -->
  HTMLConent
</div>
<div>
  <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: {"ID" : "cp_tcm:13-287251", "ComponentID" : "tcm:13-287251", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:13-286965-32", "Version" : 3, "IsQueryBased" : true  } -->
  HTMLConent
</div>
```

SiteEdit Settings

```
<!-- SiteEdit Settings: { "PageID" : "tcm:13-287332-64", "PageVersion" : 2, "TargetTypeID" : "", "ComponentPresentationLocation" : 1, "BluePrinting" : { "PageContext" : "tcm:0-8-1", "ComponentContext" : "tcm:0-13-1", "PublishContext" : "tcm:0-13-1"}} -->
```

I am getting above html on run time. I am able to open only first component using siteedit on hovering on first CP and nothing happens if I hover on any other CPs.

Also there is no JS error on page.

Thanks,
Vikas Kumar

Comment: by the way, using version = 0 in your SE_CP_Markup can give unwanted messages about your content not being the latest version, you should consider placing the current version of the Component in there

Comment: Doesn't SiteEdit 2009 SP3 only support Tridion 2011? I think SP2 is the one you need.

Comment: @RobStevenson-Leggett Yes we are using SP2 only, I have modified the question

Comment: Do the other Component Presentations show a border at all? If so, what color is that border?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SiteEdit Component Presentation markup should always be wrapped in an HTML element like a DIV for instance, that way SiteEdit can distinguish the beginning and end of your Component Presentation.

So in your loop you should output something like:

```xml
<div>
    <xsl:value-of select="XXXX:RegexStringReplace($SE_CP_MarkUP,'%ID%',@ID)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    <!-- output the content here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Wrap it in a <div> or <article> please. Wrapping it in a span will just break other things on WebKit browser - and it's showing your age.

Comment: sorry for showing my age, true any HTML element will do and DIV or ARTICLE are probably a better choice indeed (I remember now we had massive issues when using SPAN trying to get the HTML validated ;o). updated accordingly...

Comment: Sorry i dint mention but I do already have div around as you all suggested. Regarding version I am not getting any message as of now but I can provide the correct version as well.

Comment: Then I think you need to provide a lot more detail as in what you have setup and what is not working for you exactly. Like are you getting an error, if so what, or what do you exactly mean with it is not working for you. Has the full HTML on the page been validated (invalid HTML is a known issue for SiteEdit not to work), are there any JavaScript errors on the page that might be in the way etc. etc. Please edit the question and add all the additional information in it or it will be impossible for anybody to provide you with a suitable answer.

Comment: @BartKoopman I have updated question again with more detail. I am not getting any error on JS error, siteedit just not taking all CPs.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for looking at this, I just realized SiteEdit is doing its job. All SiteEdit markup divs have the same absolute position such that where ever I hover, the div shows at the top.

I am working with the design team to get it sorted.

Thanks,
Vikas Kumar

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted Vikas! I'd never have thought of that one. <grin>

Comment: we fixed the issue of overlapping SiteEdit div as well by switching off isotopes query JS, which was conflicting with SiteEdit

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would say this is due to not giving each Component Presentation a unique ID. 
But it looks like you've got that covered already.

I assume you have omitted the Setting comment from your question simply out of concern for brevity, right?

Is there any chance that you could give us the entire HTML? Remove any sensitive content, of course, but please verify that you still have the issue after you have done so.

Comment: Also, I believe it should be "ComponentVersion" instead of "Version", although I don't think that's the cause of this particular issue.

Comment: For what it's worth: I copied your markup to my own site, changed the URIs to match my system, and added a Settings comment. Works like a charm. So we definitely need more info about what problem you are experiencing...

Comment: I have added page setting as well in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the user has rights to all Component's? And do they all exist

It's probably easiest to check in the developer tools of your browser. Find the request for `GetComponentAndSchemas`.

In the body of that request (so the part that is sent to the server) you will find all Components that SiteEdit is asking for. So if that doesn't cover **all** of your Components, it somehow didn't find them in the HTML.

Then in the response of that request you should find the Components that were requested plus the Schemas that they are based on. If some Components are not present, they are somehow filtered out on the server. Most likely because the user doesn't have rights, but it could also be that they don't exist in publication 13.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue particularly if you have any html5 tags around siteedit span/div tags. Have you checked this article (from Bart), it might help. It helped in my case.

http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/siteedit_zindex.aspx

Comment: Those problems typically start from not having properly nested HTML. If you tell the SiteEdit TBBs to put a <span> around Component Presentations (as they do by default), your HTML will become invalid as as you put a simple <div> in there. And that means WebKit-based browsers (Chrome, Safari) will start re-ordering the DOM and you end up with a tiny box around your Component Presentation (that doesn't contain any fields).

Comment: we fixed the issue of overlapping SiteEdit div as well by switching off isotopes query JS, which was conflicting with SiteEdit